# I have tried to call api in reactjs class but the api called many times even on the redux api calling on functional component api called many time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, redux

Firstly i have created a function within in react class and then this function i have called within componentDidMount function. But during api calling the api called many times. Can any one please help me how to slove this problem?

```
async fetchgraphdetails(){
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': `Bearer ${BARRIER_TOKEN}`},
            body: JSON.stringify({ graphdtasetID: this.props.param.datasetGraphID })
        };

        await fetch(API_URL+'getgraphdetails',requestOptions).then(res => res.json()).then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({ downloadFlag: 0 });
                this.setState({ apiurl: result['graph'][0]['apiendpoint'] });
                this.setState({ jsondata: result['graph'][0]['jsondata'] });
                this.setState({ axislabeling: result['graph'][0]['axislabeling'] });
                this.setState({ serieslabeling: result['graph'][0]['serieslabeling'] });
                this.setState({ axiscontrol: result['graph'][0]['axiscontrol'] });
                this.setState({ heatmap: result['graph'][0]['heatmap'] });
                this.setState({ sliderplay: result['graph'][0]['sliderplay'] });
                this.setState({ defaultCountry: result['country'].join(';').toLowerCase()});
                this.setState({ byDefaultCountryList: result['country'] });
                this.setState({ categoryTitle: result['graph'][0]['categorytitle'] });
                this.setState({ datasetTitle: result['graph'][0]['title'] });
                this.setState({ description: result['graph'][0]['description'] });
                this.setState({ startYear: (result['graph'][0]['startyear']) ? result['graph'][0]['startyear'] : 2000 });
                this.setState({ endYear: (result['graph'][0]['endyear']) ? result['graph'][0]['endyear'] : 2020 });
                this.setState({ timeSliderYear: result['graph'][0]['sliderYear'] });
                this.setState({ yearStep: result['graph'][0]['yearstep'] });
                this.setState({ rounding: result['graph'][0]['rounding'] });
                this.setState({ decimalplace: result['graph'][0]['decimalplace'] });
            },(error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    }
```

```
async componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchgraphdetails();
          this.creategraph();
    }
```

Comment: Is something remounting ***this*** component, or it's parent, or some ancestor, to cause it to continually make fetch requests? Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we've more context?

Comment: each setState function is calling a re-render. Please avoid so many setState, only use one after getting the response.

Comment: @ValRob True that they could all be combined into a single `setState` statement, React batch processes enqueued updates, each one individually doesn't trigger a rerender.